# Could not find function "write.delim" whereas it can find "read.delim"

Tags: r

```
install.packages("readr")
setwd("~/Desktop/R_programing")
library(readr)

test <- read.delim(file='inpatient.tsv',header=TRUE, sep="\t")
test

colnames(test) [3:4] <- c("COL3","COL4")
write.delim(test, file = "result.tsv")
help.search("write.delim")
```

Here is my code, the function read.delim works fine however the line write.delim throws an error:

```
  could not find function "write.delim"
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Because there isn't that function in base R

Comment: The ‘readr’ package is completely unrelated to this: `read.delim` is a *base R* function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readr` package includes `write_delim` instead of `write.delim`

```
write_delim(test, file = "result.tsv")
```

Comment: ah ... so they were meaning to use readr functions

Comment: You should have written this as a comment and voted to close. It's just a misspelling problem.

Comment: @IRTFM what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231356/how-to-subset-dataframe-based-on-values-that-do-not-match-in-two-columns-in-r/69231403#69231403) then?  I see almost 100s of subset questions asked over the years